# How to build your own custom session store class?

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, session

By default, sessions are stored in browser cookies (:cookie_store), but you can also specify one of the other included stores (:active_record_store, :mem_cache_store, or **your own custom class.** Please give me the way to build custom class

```
config.action_controller.session_store = :your_customer_class
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Maurício Linhares is correct, however, I wanted to add some detail because I don't think it's obvious which methods you need to implement.

You can inherit from [ActionDispatch::Session::AbstractStore](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/actionpack/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/session/abstract_store.rb), but that inherits from [Rack::Session::Abstract::ID](https://github.com/rack/rack/blob/master/lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb) which is a good place to look for the methods you need to implement. Specifically, from [Rack::Session::Abstract::ID](https://github.com/rack/rack/blob/master/lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb):

```
# All thread safety and session retrival proceedures should occur here.
# Should return [session_id, session].
# If nil is provided as the session id, generation of a new valid id
# should occur within.

def get_session(env, sid)
  raise '#get_session not implemented.'
end

# All thread safety and session storage proceedures should occur here.
# Should return true or false dependant on whether or not the session
# was saved or not.

def set_session(env, sid, session, options)
  raise '#set_session not implemented.'
end

# All thread safety and session destroy proceedures should occur here.
# Should return a new session id or nil if options[:drop]

def destroy_session(env, sid, options)
  raise '#destroy_session not implemented'
end
```

I wrote a simple [file-based session store](https://gist.github.com/3335006) as an experiment.

Comment: Inheriting `Rack::Session::Abstract::ID` has been deprecated. Now it should be `Rack::Session::Abstract::Persisted`.

Comment: Another real-life example is the [`redis-session-store`](https://github.com/roidrage/redis-session-store) gem.

Answer (score 1):

To implement your own session store, the easiest solution is to inherit from [**ActionDispatch::Session::AbstractStore**](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/actionpack/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/session/abstract_store.rb) and implement the necessary methods. The [CookieStore](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/actionpack/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/session/cookie_store.rb) is a quite simple implementation and should possibly get you started.